# Unable to call child function from parent using refs with functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I am working on React and calling child function from parent in but when I call current on my ref it gives me undefined.

Actually refs are perfectly working for previous Parent component and even calling the `useImperativeHandle` functions as well but when using `useImperativeHandle` to call another child refs it gives undefined on current.

```
export const ZoneMapView = forwardRef((props,ref) => {
  const draw_map=useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    call: ()=> {
      alert(draw_map.current);
    }
  }));
  return (
    <div className="map-view">
      <BaseMap ref={draw_map}/>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Call Method is being called from Parent component but then Getting undefined on `alert(draw_map.current)`. How to access child functions ?Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you wanting to call `BaseMap` functions from `ZoneMapView`?

Comment: Yes But when Call method is called from Another Parent component

Comment: You say `useImperativeHandle` works, but that using `useImperativeHandle` to call another child refs doesn't. Are you trying to call a method from a Parent > Child > Child component?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Yes, sir you got it

Comment: I updated my solution based on this structure, let us know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm early in my own education of `useRef` and `useImperativeHandle`, but here's my understanding of it.

It's hard to tell from the code provided in your question how the components are setup, but it sounds like you want to call a method from a nested child component. Meaning you have a

`Parent` > `Middle` > `Child`

component structure, and want to call a method from `Child` in `Parent`.

To do this, you can pass the `ref` through the `Middle` component to the `Child` allowing the `Child` method to be called in the `Parent`.

However, it seems this could be handled in a simpler, easier to understand way - for example, using Redux, or passing a function to the child as a prop. Without seeing your full code it's hard to make recommendations.

Here's a simplified demo:

```js
const Child = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef();
  
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log('button click')
  }
  
  const childStyle = {
    margin: 20
  }
  
  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    click: () => {
      buttonRef.current.click()
    }
  }))

  return (
    <button ref={buttonRef} style={childStyle} onClick={handleClick}>Child Component</button>
  )
})

const Middle = ({childRef}) => {
  const middleStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'darkgray'
  }

  return (
    <div style={middleStyle}>
      Middle Component
      <Child ref={childRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = React.useRef()
  
  const parentStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    padding: 20
  }
  
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    /*
    *   CALL A METHOD FROM THE CHILD
    */
    childRef.current.click()
  }
  
  return (
    <div style={parentStyle} onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}>
      <p>
        Parent Component<br />
        onMouseEnter of this gray area the onClick of the button will be called
      </p>
      <Middle childRef={childRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Here I have three components Parent with its child `ZoneMapView` and then `ZoneMapView ` has child `Basemap` So Parent is calling `call` method successfully but when I call the subsequent child function (with same settings) it gives undefined

Comment: I have updated the solution to show how this can be done.

Comment: Yes This is what I wanted working perfectly here trying to replicate it in my code

Comment: Great! And please remember to accept the answer that answers your question :)