# Is there a way to access a function returned by a React component through a parent HTMLDivElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom `React` component, `Foo`, which contains another custom component, `SubFoo`, which in turn contains an inline library component, `<Bar/>`.From `Foo` I need to access a function, `BarFunc`, which is returned by `<Bar/>`. Unfortunately, `<Bar/>` is not set up to work with `ref`s - when I try to pass in a `ref` to `<Bar/>` (forwarded from `Foo` to `SubFoo` using `React.forwardRef()`), I get `undefined`.

However, there is a `div` that is parent to `<Bar/>` in `SubFoo`, and if I pass my `ref` to this `div` I get back an `HTMLDivElement`.

Is there any way to execute `BarFunc` given my `HTMLDivElement`?

Comment: Made an omission - the `HTMLDivElement` comes from the first child of the `div` returned by `ref`

Comment: Are you saying that you have a component that returns a `function`, or are you saying that you have a functional component `Bar` that you can't take a `ref` to that returns a sub-component with a `BarFunc` API that you want access to?  If the former, how is the function used by `SubFoo` (since, as I understand it, React doesn't know how to render `() => "Magic"` if it's returned from a component _as a function_)?

Comment: Can you give us some code to work with?

Comment: I have a component that returns some HTML as well as a `function`. The documentation for `Bar` actually calls this function a 'returned value' (the documentation is essentially just a list of `props` and returned values). The `function` isn't used by `SubFoo`, the `div` + component is just returned by `SubFoo` with certain `props`. I need to call it when a certain event happen in `Foo`

Comment: @7iiBob Here is a fiddle. In reality there is more complicated stuff going on than just an `onClick`, but including that would just make this messier https://jsfiddle.net/h4fucgsq/

Comment: @SeanVieira This is the component I'm using. Specifically I want to use the `setTransform` function
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinchc

Comment: @Enquisidor Can you create an instance of Bar within Foo, use there and   pass it down to SubFoo as a prop instead of the ref?

Comment: Unfortunately `SubFoo` is actually a component that is used elsewhere, and the props of `Bar` use state in `SubFoo`. If I created `Bar` within `Foo`, I would have to lift up the state of `SubFoo` into every file that uses it. Would be very messy.

Comment: What about using the context api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you are looking to do:

1. Modify `SubFoo` to proxy the behavior that `Bar` provides via its `render`-prop.  Then `Foo` can take a reference to `SubFoo` and invoke the behavior indirectly:

   ```js
   class SubFoo extends React.Component {
     barBehavior = () => this.barBehaviorFunc?.()

     renderProp = barApi => {
       this.barBehaviorFunc = barApi.barBehavior;
       return <div><other components={here} /></div>;
     }

     render() {
       return <Bar>{this.renderProp}</Bar>;
     }
   }

   class Foo extends React.Component {
     onClick() { this.ref?.barBehavior();
     render() {
       return <SubFoo ref={r => this.ref = r} />
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use the `React.Context` API to expose this behavior upwards (if you have unmodifiable code in between `Foo` and `SubFoo`).

   ```js
   const BarBehaviorContext = React.createContext(() => {});

   class Foo extends React.Component {
     setBarBehavior = barBehavior => this.barBehavior = barBehavior;
     render() { return <BarBehaviorContext.Provider value={this.setBarBehavior}><SubFoo /></BarBehaviorContext.Provider>;
   }

   class SubFoo extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return <BarBehaviorContext.Consumer>{setter => <Bar>{api => (setter(api.barBehavior), <div>...</div>)}</Bar>}</BarBehaviorContext.Consumer>
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @seanvieira, solution 2 seems to be working for me!

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in that last comment. Solution 1 is working for me. However I needed to use part of the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389181/unable-to-call-child-function-from-parent-using-refs-with-functional-component) as well, specifically the part about `React.useImperativeHandle`